# "Using index condition; Using where" explaining my query, with proper indexes?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-design, query-optimization

From the manual *Using index condition; Using where*:

> By accessing index tuples and testing them initially, tables can be
> read while deferring the reading of full rows until it is essential.

I've the following table columns:

- `attendance_in_date`: DATE
- `attendance_out_date`: DATE
- `attendance_user_id`: BIGINT
- `attendance_headquarter_id`: BIGINT

The following `WHERE` applies (`?` denotes an optional condition):

- ✅ **SET 1**: `attendance_in_date, attendance_user_id, attendance_headquarter_id?` => covered by an `INDEX in_date_user_id_headquarter_id` (cover all the columns):

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM attendance
WHERE 
    attendance_in_date = DATE(NOW()) 
    AND 
    attendance_user_id = 5 
    AND 
    attendance_headquarter_id = 4
```

- ✅ **SET 2**: `attendance_in_date, attendance_out_date, attendance_headquarter_id?` => convered by an `INDEX in_date_out_date_headquarter_id` (cover all the columns)

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM attendance
WHERE 
    attendance_in_date = DATE(NOW())
    AND 
    attendance_out_date IS NULL 
    AND 
    attendance_headquarter_id = 4
```

- ❌ **SET 3**: `attendance_in_date, attendance_out_date, attendance_user_id, attendance_headquarter_id` => can't get *Using index*

**SET 3** is problematic. No matter the index I try to create, I always get *Using index condition; Using where*. Example query:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM attendance
WHERE 
    attendance_in_date = DATE(NOW()) 
    AND 
    attendance_out_date IS NULL 
    AND 
    attendance_user_id = 5 
    AND 
    attendance_headquarter_id = 4
```

Any idea on how to get the **SET 3** covered by and index?

Comment: Show the EXPLAIN. Which index is it choosing? It's under the `key` column of the EXPLAIN. It isn't necessarily the one you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Have one index with all 4 columns in any order.

To handle all 3 cases with a single index:

```
INDEX(in_date, out_date,        -- in either order
      user_id, headquarter_id)  -- in either order
```

In the order I just listed, it will be "perfect" for cases 1 and 3, while being pretty good for case 2.

Alternatively, have two indexes -- one to handle two of the case, plus another to handle the other case "better":

```
INDEX(in_date, out_date, headquarter_id)   -- in any order
```

Notes:

- If `*` (after `SELECT`) includes columns other than those mentioned in the index, it is not "covering".  Phrased differently:
- If *all* columns *anywhere* in the `SELECT` are in the `INDEX` *anywhere*, the `INDEX` is called "covering".  That is indicated by "Using index".
- "Using index condition" (aka ICP or "index condition pushdown") means something different -- some of the processing is done one place, some is "pushed" off to another place.  This is "good" but *usually* not "best".